# Adding title element to paperjs SVG (using node.js)

Tags: node.js, svg, element, paperjs, jsdom

I would like to add a `<title>` element to an SVG file generate with [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) and its [*exportSVG*](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#exportsvg) function, within a node.js application (using *paperjs-jsdom* package)

So far, my files look like this :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="642" height="377" viewBox="0,0,642,377">
<g> 
...
</g></svg>
```

And I would like it to look like this :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="642" height="377" viewBox="0,0,642,377">
<title>toto</title>
<g> 
...
</g></svg>
```

I have looked into [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) (which should be included in the *paperjs-jsdom* package), trying to load `<svg>` content in a DOM, but I have not been able to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is just adding a `<title>` tag after the `<svg>` tag, a workaround without even using JSDOM could be to use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp).
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.3/S/VVHdS8MwEP9XjiK0w9Hqgy91FmSKT4JQ8WUfcKa3NltMyiVblbL/3aS1ooEc9/H7OJI+0vhBUR6VB3KiieaRMFWoswweGDtAEJKFonTNa62pgxd0TbocekkfmuCPIO2IczhJ6tKxmE8zxkoebQ43V7+tnVRqaZTxjNgw6priMDrPQgzXuz9+toadt2uJ072Fls2ehAO0UL49gXUsdT1sdUIGe6rhbsKkNHA9LOnRlgMyd3yk8+z2j8N9VYGTThHgzi8MCy9SgMNRdVT0MWVqFQpKsmQbIKttsbksZtkc4ovrxSBQPH/Ba0gW2VjH/4zKxnTAZI/KgdQgjLbm50WnXJk68dojzf/COxMeWiO1s1G+2py/AQ==) demonstrating the solution.

```
// Draw a circle.
new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
})

// Export Paper.js project as SVG string.
var svg = project.exportSVG({asString:true});

// Add title after <svg> tag.
svg = svg.replace(/(^<svg[^>]+>)/, '$1<title>My Title</title>');

// Show result in console.
console.log(svg);
```

Result is:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1151" height="937" viewBox="0,0,1151,937">
    <title>My Title</title>
    <g fill="#ffa500" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
        <path d="M525.5,468.5c0,-27.61424 22.38576,-50 50,-50c27.61424,0 50,22.38576 50,50c0,27.61424 -22.38576,50 -50,50c-27.61424,0 -50,-22.38576 -50,-50z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Well, that is working fine indeed (thanks for the tip, I am not truly familiar with RegEXp), but for a more general use (and probably later needs), I will keep looking for a more generic solution